# It's just a big mess

Tags: meaning-in-context

> “Just a Big Mess”
>
> In this press release the senior author of the new study, Sergio Almécija, a senior research scientist at the American Museum of Natural History, is also quoted as offering this remarkable admission: “When you look at the narrative for hominin origins, it’s ***just*** a big mess — there’s no consensus whatsoever.”

Source: https://evolutionnews.org/2021/05/scientists-conclude-human-origins-research-is-a-big-mess/

---

It appears to me that "***just***" means "very, such", but I'm not certain.
I'd like to know the meaning of "***just***".

Comment: In this case, it likely means "nothing more than"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this context, you could substitute **nothing but** or **simply** for the word **just**:

It's just a big mess.

It's nothing but a big mess.

It's simply a big mess.